# In a Snowflake stored procedure, what are the benefits of choosing "DECLARE" variable over "LET" variables (and visa versa)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake you can declare variable before the `BEGIN` block using `DECLARE` and after the `BEGIN` block using `LET`.

This example from Snowflake illustrates it:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
    DECLARE
        profit number(38, 2) DEFAULT 0.0;
    BEGIN
        LET cost number(38, 2) := 100.0;
        LET revenue number(38, 2) DEFAULT 110.0;

        profit := revenue - cost;
        RETURN profit;
    END;
$$
;
```

Note how profit is created using DECLARE and cost and revenue are created using LET.

I understand that syntactically that is what is required. That is not my question.

My question is: **Why would you choose to `DECLARE` some variables and create other variables using the `LET` statement? What is the difference?** It seems I could put all my variable in the `DECLARE` block or define all my variables locally using `LET` and there would be no difference. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion one of main difference is the programming style and the decision when to declare variables - SCOPE.

Option 1:

At the beginning of the block - `DECLARE` part. One single place to keep all variables.

Visibility: block-wise scope.

Option 2:

Declaring variable as close to the place of actual use as possible using `LET`.

Visibility: It has limited scope of the block(from place of defining to the end of the block) or inside specific control construct(loop constructs).

---

Example:

`LET` inside loop has scope of loop only.

```
DECLARE
    profit  DEFAULT 0.0;
BEGIN
    FOR counter IN  1 TO 5 DO
         LET cost number(38, 2) := 100.0;   -- visibility limited only to FOR
    END FOR;
   
    LET revenue number(38, 2) DEFAULT 110.0;
    profit := revenue - cost;
    RETURN profit;
END;
-- Error: invalid identifier 'COST' (line 10)
```

vs.:

```
DECLARE
    profit  DEFAULT 0.0;
    cost number(38,2) := 100.0;    -- visible in entire block
BEGIN
    FOR counter IN  1 TO 5 DO
          cost := 50.0;
    END FOR;
   
    LET revenue number(38, 2) DEFAULT 110.0;
    profit := revenue - cost;
    RETURN profit;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Lukasz. So basically, apart from block level scoping, there isn't really any practical difference. That is helpful.