# Set vs let vs declaring variables in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone explain to me what the differences are between `SET`, `LET` and `DECLARE` variables in Snowflake? I'm specifically referring to writing a stored procedure. What is the best practice?

```
create or replace procedure my_stored_proc(run_date date)
returns varchar
language SQL
as
$$
DECLARE

    date1 date DEFAULT dateadd('day',-1,:run_date);

BEGIN

    let date2 date:= dateadd('day',-1,:run_date);

    set date3 = dateadd('day',-1,:run_date);

END
```

Comment: [In a Snowflake stored procedure, what are the benefits of choosing "DECLARE" variable over "LET" variables (and visa versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75725777/5070879)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DECLARE indicates a block of code used to define variables at the start of your SP, before you want to use them.

LET is used define a single variable at the point where you want to use it.

SET is used to define session variables and is not valid syntax within a SQL scripting block.